Percona xtrabackup and percona toolkit for aarch64 Graviton Amazon Linux 2 machines
In my organisation, it was decided to move all the MySQL infrastructure (Amazon EC2 machines) to Graviton (aarch64) servers from AMD (x86_64).
All are MySQL Community Servers.
I need percona-xtrabackup and percona-toolkit installed on the new aarch64 (graviton) machines, but unfortunately, percona has not yet released the aarch64 packages. There's a lot of dependency on percona-toolkit and xtrabackup. Lots of scripts are running using percona-toolkit tools and backups are running using xtrabackup.
I know these packages can be built from source also, but I have never done it before.
I was able to build percona xtrabackup using this link
https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/compile-xtrabackup.html
and percona-toolkit (version 3.3.1) from this link https://github.com/percona/percona-toolkit/blob/3.x/INSTALL
Because I have never done this before and because Percona has not yet officially provided these packages, I am really not sure if building these packages from source will work on Graviton (aarch64) or not.
The graviton machines have Amazon Linux 2 on them. I am not even sure which Red Hat version is this.
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
SUPPORT_END="2025-06-30"

cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.219-208.866.amzn2.aarch64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-61-241) (gcc10-gcc (GCC) 10.5.0 20230707 (Red Hat 10.5.0-1), GNU ld version 2.35.2-9.amzn2.0.1) #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 14:00:02 UTC 2024

rpm -E %{rhel}
7


What's your question? Regardless, perhaps your organisation should reconsider the move to a hardware platform that is not supported by the software you depend upon.

if these packages so built from the source will work on Graviton (aarch64) or not? that's the question.

We have an aarch64 build of percona-toolkit as part of SSM (our fork of PMM v1). You can find the repository here:
https://dl.shatteredsilicon.net/ssm/9/RPMS/aarch64/
