mydumper packages availability for graviton aarch64
I am trying to implement mydumper for mysql community server (8.0), in absence of xtrabackup for graviton aarch64 architecture.
Unfortunately packages are not available for graviton aarch64 architecture in regards with percona. I found some packages for mydumper though on this link https://github.com/mydumper/mydumper/releases
Following are the two packages I found for mydumper
mydumper-0.16.3-6.el9.aarch64.rpm
mydumper-0.16.3-6.el8.aarch64.rpm

I am not sure if these packages will work for Amazon Linux 2 or not because I am unable to figure out the corresponding Linux version. It looks like RHEL 7 and no el7 package is available.
Following are the details of the Amazon Linux 2 machines.
rpm -E %{rhel}
7

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
SUPPORT_END="2025-06-30"

cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.220-209.867.amzn2.aarch64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-44-18) (gcc10-gcc (GCC) 10.5.0 20230707 (Red Hat 10.5.0-1), GNU ld version 2.35.2-9.amzn2.0.1) #1 SMP Fri Jun 28 16:53:54 UTC 2024

And there's no say for me in which OS to use.

Have you tried compiling Percona's XtraBackup for RHEL/Fedora and running it?

And the normal mysqldump doesn't work? You would need to write you own schema

@Vérace I have compiled xtrabackup successfully, but because the packages are not provided by Percona yet for aarch64. I am really not sure if it works or not. The same thing I have asked in the following question
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/341067/percona-xtrabackup-and-percona-toolkit-for-aarch64-graviton-amazon-linux-2-machi

@nbk of course the normal mysqldump works but we have large databases, if i use mysqldump, it would take a lot longer. Hence looking for an alternate.

With large databases I recommend a replucation and a backup of the replicated server, so that the normal business can proceed

Well, have you tried running your compiled code? You don't need a package - I mean, I've never compiled XtraBackup, but I've compiled MySQL (and PostgreSQL and Firebird) loads of times and I just run them from the command line directly - they're not "installed" - but that just means they're not on the $PATH - the packages just install things where they will be found and makes sure they're started on booting - try running your compiled executable and see - try with a couple of sample databases first!

@nbk of course I won't run backups on master, a separate slave is dedicated for backups. the question is of the time taken by mysqldump, hence looking for an alternate like xtrabackup which is unavailable for Graviton aarch64

@Vérace I have not yet tried it, I will try it on a test server and check. let's see

@Vérace I have tried the compiled xtrabackup for restoring a machine, took xtrabackup from AMD (prod slave) and restored it on GRAVITON (test server) and it seems working. Since last 7 days I have kept the test slave running and so far it has not complained about anything. I just wanted to run a pt-table-checksum (built the same way percona-toolkit) once but for some reason pt-table-checksum isn't working. Thank you very much for your help though :-).
